# XSL distinct sub nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have and xml

```
<Top>
    <Node1>
        <Class1>
            <Test name="test1"></Test>
            <Test name="test2"></Test>
        </Class1>
    </Node1>
    <Node2>
        <Class1>
            <Test name="test1"></Test>
            <Test name="test2"></Test>
        </Class1>
    </Node2>
</Top>
```

Desired result:

test1  --  Node1 && Node2

test2  --  Node1 && Node2

I tried using Distinct, but I am doing something wrong.

Can some one help me with this one..

Thanks,
Girish

Comment: I don't understand your requirement. Can you explain how you arrived at that output? Maybe show another example?

Answer (score 1):

**I. Here is a simple XSLT 1.0 solution, using the [Muenchian grouping method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kTestByName" match="Test"
          use="@name"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "Test
     [generate-id()
     =
      generate-id(key('kTestByName', @name)[1])
     ]
  ">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "concat(@name, ' -- ')"/>

  <xsl:apply-templates mode="group"
      select="key('kTestByName', @name)"/>
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Test" mode="group">
  <xsl:if test="position() > 1"> &amp;&amp; </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="name(../..)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Top>
    <Node1>
        <Class1>
            <Test name="test1"></Test>
            <Test name="test2"></Test>
        </Class1>
    </Node1>
    <Node2>
        <Class1>
            <Test name="test1"></Test>
            <Test name="test2"></Test>
        </Class1>
    </Node2>
</Top>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
test1 -- Node1 && Node2
test2 -- Node1 && Node2
```

**II. An XSLT 2.0 solution** using **[`<xsl:for-each-group>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group)** and the functions **[`current-group()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#current-group)** and **[`current-grouping-key()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#current-grouping-key)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="*/*/Test"
                      group-by="@name">
   <xsl:value-of select=
   "concat(current-grouping-key(), ' -- ')"/>

   <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
   <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Test">
  <xsl:if test="position() > 1"> &amp;&amp; </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="name(../..)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this XSLT 2.0 transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same wanted and correct result is produced**:

```
test1 -- Node1 && Node2
test2 -- Node1 && Node2
```