# Transform XML nested Data to Flat overview Table with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, html-table

I have xml-Data like:

```
<rootNode>
    <subNode name="sn1">
        <node name="field2" value="23"/>
        <node name="field4" value="24"/>
    </subNode>
    <subNode name="sn2">
        <node name="field2" value="39"/>
    </subNode>
    <subNode name="sn3">
        <subNode name="f1">
            <node name="field2" value="23"/>
            <node name="field4" value="24"/>
        </subNode>
        <node name="field2" value="23"/>
        <node name="field8" value="24"/>
    </subNode>
</rootNode>
```

The depth of the nodes is infinit. sunNode can be inside every subNode. node can just be inside a subNode.

And I would like to transform it into a table like:

```
+-----------+-----+-----+-----+
| Field     | sn1 | sn2 | sn3 |
|-----------+-----+-----+-----+
|field2     |  23 |  39 |  23 |
|-----------+-----+-----+-----+
|field4     |  24 | n/a | n/a |
|-----------+-----+-----+-----+
|field8     | n/a | n/a |  24 |
|-----------+-----+-----+-----+
|f1->field2 | n/a | n/a |  23 |
|-----------+-----+-----+-----+
|f1->field4 | n/a | n/a |  24 +
+-----------+-----+-----+-----+
```

So I have to search for every possible "node" inside every "subNode" and create a row for each of them. Then, if there is an entry for the top-SubNode, display the value.

With

```
<xsl:for-each select="subNode//node()">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I get at least a list of all the Elements that are in the Data. But that list is not distinct.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408181/xsl-distinct-sub-nodes) but can't apply it to my needs.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

XSLT converts one form of XML to another from of XML. It does not convert XML to a formatted display like you have shown by itself. For that, you need to use something like FOP.